# Update table1 field with table2 field value in join laravel fluent

Tags: laravel-4

```
$table = 'favorite_contents';
$contents = DB::table($table)
        ->join('contents', function($join) use($table){
            $join->on("$table.content_id", '=', 'contents.id');
        })
        ->whereIn("$table.content_id",$ids)
        ->update(array(
                "$table.expired" => 1,
                "$table.type" => "contents.type"
        ));
```

The `"$table.expired" => 1` is working fine, but the `"$table.type" => "contents.type"` doesn't.

So the problem has something to do with getting the value of type in the contents table, how do I do this without resorting to foreach?

Answer (score 1):

Change `"$table.type" => "contents.type"` to `"$table.type" => DB::raw("contents.type")`. As you have it, I believe the `update()` method is trying to save the string "contents.type" rather than getting the "type" column from "contents". If you're using MySQL and the favorite_contents.type is numeric column, it might convert "contents.type" to 0 without showing an error.