# How to do update query on laravel fluent using db::raw

Tags: laravel

This is related to one of my question earlier where:

[Update table1 field with table2 field value in join laravel fluent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111763/update-table1-field-with-table2-field-value-in-join-laravel-fluent)

But since this is a different approach now, I will just ask another question:

**How do you properly do an update using `DB:raw`?**

I want to update the `favorite_contents.type` with the value of contents.type, but it doesn't do anything, the static setting of 1 to `favorite_contents.expired` is working.

This is my code which still doesn't update the type even when the `DB::raw` was used:

```
$table = 'favorite_contents';
$contents = DB::table($table)
            ->join('contents', function($join) use($table){
                $join->on("$table.content_id", '=', 'contents.id');
            })
            ->whereIn("$table.content_id",$ids)
            ->update(array(
                    "$table.expired" => 1
            ));

DB::raw("UPDATE favorite_contents, contents SET favorite_contents.type = contents.type where favorite_contents.content_id = contents.id");
```

This is the first code that doesn't update before I resorted to the above code that doesn't work as well:

```
$table = 'favorite_contents';
$contents = DB::table($table)
        ->join('contents', function($join) use($table){
            $join->on("$table.content_id", '=', 'contents.id');
        })
        ->whereIn("$table.content_id",$ids)
        ->update(array(
                "$table.expired" => 1,
                "$table.type" => "contents.type"
        ));
```

P.S:
This is working when done on an sql editor:

`UPDATE favorite_contents, contents SET favorite_contents.type = contents.type where favorite_contents.content_id = contents.id`

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
DB::statement("UPDATE favorite_contents, contents SET favorite_contents.type = contents.type where favorite_contents.content_id = contents.id");
```

Try `DB::statement` for raw queries that does not involve outputting something (select).

Comment: It's true that this is why his DB::raw() statement didn't execute anything.  But the other answer that shows how to use DB::raw() within an update() is probably what most people viewing this question are probably looking for.

Answer (score 113):

code raw updates like this:

```
...->update( array(
    'column' => DB::raw( 'column * 2' )
) );
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer as it keeps true to the ORM as much as possible, and reduces the amount of raw SQL needed.

Comment: But ... How to set parameters for DB:raw in update statement?!

Answer (score 37):

Will be work such similar, simple realization in Laravel 5.2 ,
Query Builder:

```
DB::table('stores')
            ->where('id', $request)
            ->update(['visibility' =>DB::raw($value)]);
```

This response is tested real site and working properly