# Get row id in batch update

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to optimize the below mentioned `foreach` loop

```
foreach($idsNoLongerInResponse as $offerId) {
  $offerId = $offerId->id;

  $offer = Offer::find($offerId);
  $offer->notes = "updated offer [offer_id=$offer->id]";

  $offer->save();
}
```

I have optimized that but I'm not sure how should I get the ID for each row while batch updating.

```
 Offer::whereIn('id', $idsNoLongerInResponse)->update([
    'some_updates' => 1,

    // How can I get the row id here?
    'notes' => "updated offer [offer_id=$offer->id]"
]);
```

Am I going in the wrong direction? Any help would be appreciated. If possible please provide the solution in laravel eloquent and raw query format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a DB::raw in the update

```
...->update( array(
    'column' => DB::raw( 'column * 2' )
) );
```

Check discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113025/how-to-do-update-query-on-laravel-fluent-using-dbraw)

So, following your example, I think you can try this solution

```
Offer::whereIn('id', $idsNoLongerInResponse)->update([
    'some_updates' => 1,

    // How can I get the row id here?
    'notes' => DB::raw('CONCAT(CONCAT("updated offer [offer_id=", bot_offer_id), "]")')
]);
```